# Grouping data for boxplot by month (and plotting chronologically)

Tags: r

Let's say I have a 3 variables that were collected over 2 years

```
Var1 <- c(1:20)
Var2 <- c(41:60)
Var3<-c(81:100)
Date<- sample(seq(as.Date('2000/01/01'), as.Date('2002/12/31'), by="day"), 60)
data<-data.frame(Var1,Var2,Var3,Date)
```

I could like to create boxplots for each variable, combining by month, then plotting the months chronologically (Jan-Dec).

Right now my code looks like

```
boxplot(data$Var1 ~ reorder(format(data$Date,'%b %y'),data$Date))
```

or

```
boxplot(data$Var1~months(data$Date))
```

this gives me the full two years in chronological order, rather than just Months, or the months but in alphabetical order.
Hope that makes sense! I am new to R but am learning ggplot as well.

Comment: Why do you not change the values in column *Date* to include only the month, but not the year, e.g. with the *substr* function?

Comment: Please add some reproducible data

Comment: I can extract the months from the dates, but then I have the problem that they plot alphabetically, not chronologically

Comment: @GabrielleMacklin your question needs reproducible data, make sure you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: Okay I edited to hopefully make it easier with some example data

Answer (score 0):

You have to reorder the month names proberly:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(forcats)

data2 <- 
  data %>% 
  mutate(
    month = format(Date, "%m"),
    label = format(Date, "%b"),
    label = fct_reorder(label, month, min)
  )
boxplot(data2$Var1 ~ data2$label)
```